# PyQt custom dock tooltip for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt

I work with PyQt5 and [PyDM](https://slaclab.github.io/pydm/) in a few ubuntu and debian distributions and i need a way of setting tooltips for the application icon on the ubuntu bar as show in the image:

[image]

I need to do this via python code.
The way im calling the application seems to be the reason why the tooltip text in the image is set to "testing" but i its still not in python code.

I have a .ui file named example.ui. I call it in a pydm/python script named example.py:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/pydm

from pydm import Display
from os import path

class Main(Display):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, args=None, macros=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent=parent, args=args, macros=None)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.blah)

    def blah(self):
        print("BLAH")

    def ui_filename(self):
        return "example.ui"

    def ui_filepath(self):
        # Return the full path to the UI file
        return path.join("./", "example.ui")
```

finallly, i have a .sh script called init.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

pydm -m "MY_MACRO=Example" example.py testing
```

If i change "testing" in the init.sh file, the tooltip also changes accordingly but, as i said, i want to do this via the .py file.

If it helps, i know Qt MainWindow is accessible via

> QApplication.instance().main_window

For example, you can do:

> QApplication.instance().main_window.setMaximumSize(some_number,some_number)

But i found nothing in [QApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#windowIcon-prop) documentation about application tooltips.

Comment: I also tried QApplication.instance().main_window.setWindowTitle("BLAH") but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Python receives information from the command line in the form of [*args and **kwargs](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/).  In this case, *args.  'testing' is an example of an arg.  --input='testing' is an example of a kwarg (keyword argument).

Change this line:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None, args=None, macros=None):
```

To this:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None, args=['testing'], macros=None):
```

For more information, look into the `__init__()` 'dunder' method and the 'Display' object code that's being imported from pydm:

[PyDM Display Object Code](https://github.com/slaclab/pydm/blob/master/pydm/display.py)

Answer:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/pydm

from pydm import Display
from os import path

class Main(Display):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, args=['testing'], macros=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent=parent, args=args, macros=None)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.blah)

    def blah(self):
        print("BLAH")

    def ui_filename(self):
        return "example.ui"

    def ui_filepath(self):
        # Return the full path to the UI file
        return path.join("./", "example.ui")
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! However, this answer is not working for me: i removed the argument "testing" in the init.sh file after `pydm -m "MY_MACRO=example" example.py` and added `args=["testing"]` to my init function. The tooltip changed from "testing" to "Unknown".